# Fubini's theorem for Probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,B,\mu)$ be a probability measure space. Suppose that $f$ is measurable on $X$.

Let $g(x,y)=f(x)-f(y)$.

Suppose $g $ is $\mu \times \mu$ integrable.

Show $f$ is $\mu$- integrable.

Things I know:

$\mu(X)=1, \mu(\emptyset)=0$.

Since $g$ is $\mu \times \mu$ integrable, by Fubini's Theorem $g_x$ and $g^y$ are integrable for a.e $x$ and $y$.

From here, I'm not sure how to continue.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Fubini's theorem existos a $y_0$ such that $f(x)-f(y_0)$ is $\mu-$ integrable

That is $\int |f(x)-f(y_0)| d\mu(x)< \infty$

So $$\int|f(x)|d\mu(x) \leq \int|f(x)-f(y_0)| d\mu(x)+\int|f(y_0)| d\mu(x)$$ $$\int|f(x)-f(y_0)| d\mu(x)+|f(y_0)|<\infty$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! Just wondering, do we need that $\mu$ is a probability measure anywhere here?

Comment: @Rye we need a finite measure in general to integrate the constant number $|f(y_0)|$